# How do the Races synergize with the Slayer class?

Tags: tera

I'm looking at playing a Slayer in the coming Open Beta, and I was hoping for some feedback from people who had played more than I have in the Closed Beta, about how the racial abilities synergize with the Slayer class.  I understand how all the racials work, I'm more interested in the intersection between said abilities and the game play style of the Slayer class.  Specifically I care about PvP (though, other domains are important to me).

Comment: I couldn't decide on the correct tag for this game (as Tera is an overloaded term), so I gave two possibilities

Comment: *TERA* is the name of the game. Since no other games carry that name and it doesn't seem likely to be overloaded on GSE, I'd say go with *TERA*. :)

Comment: When I looked on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tera+&oq=tera+&aq=f&aqi=p-p1g9&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=youtube-psuggest.3..35i39j0l9.9774.9774.0.9807.1.1.0.0.0.0.29.29.1.1.0.) tera online seemed more common than tera.  The google search for Tera gave me a hodgepodge, but tera online was consistent.  That said, I'm not opposed to either one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the racial skills in *TERA* aren't meant to be super-critical in your choice of race.

That being said...

- An [Aman](http://tera.enmasse.com/game-guide/races/aman) takes 10% less damage when under 30% health. As a melee class, you'll be toe-to-toe with BAMs and if you fail to dodge (or your dodge abilities are on cooldown) than damage mitigation is nice.
- A [Baraka](http://tera.enmasse.com/game-guide/races/baraka) can heal to full every 2 hours. They also resist stuns which would otherwise inhibit your ability to dodge.
- A [Castanic](http://tera.enmasse.com/game-guide/races/castanic) crits more often when behind a mob. As a slayer who parties with others who can tank mobs, this is a nice passive ability.
- A [High Elf](http://tera.enmasse.com/game-guide/races/high-elf) can restore mana to full every 2 hours. Since the slayer's resource mechanic acts like rage (you build it with attacks and then spend it on skills), it can be nice to start at full for some encounters. Overall, though, it's not a great benefit to slayer play style.
- A [Human](http://tera.enmasse.com/game-guide/races/human) takes less damage from other players when low on health and is less susceptible to knockdowns and palatalization (which would otherwise inhibit your ability to dodge).

None of the other races synergize very well.

In the end, **I'd choose an aman or a castanic. If you're going to focus exclusively on PvP or PvP is all you will do end-game, then Human is not a bad choice either.**

Comment: What is the difference between the Aman and human racials. `Last Aman Standing` and `No Stranger to Pain` seem the same as `Deft Footwork` and `Indomitable Spirit`.

Comment: `No Stranger to Pain` applies to PvE damage as well as PvP damage, whereas `Indomitable Spirit` is PvP only. The threshholds and damage mitigated may be different as well but I'd need to confirm that. As for `Last Aman Standing` vs. `Deft Footwork`, I'm unsure. I'll have to look into that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto @Shaun's excellent answer, there's one more thing to consider: hitbox.

Playing as an Aman, you're one of the largest classes in the game. This is excellent for tanking damadge, as the larger your hitbox, the more that you have the chance to block. It also makes it easy for your priest to heal you, as you're easier to click. But for PVP, you stand out like a sort thumb.

And vice-versa for Elin.

Aside from hitboxes and racial abilities, the only other deciding factor of class is aesthetics.

[More about races...](http://teraguides.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/choosing-a-race)